# Windows Forms: handling two button clicks within a specific time period

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a `BRIGHT` button and a `UP` and `DOWN` button on my Windows Form. The above function is the event handling function for UpBotton click. I want the code inside the function to execute only if the user presses `BRIGHT` button followed by `UP` button within 10 seconds. How do I manage that.

```
        private void Upbutton23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (backlight_percentage < 100)
            {
                backlight_percentage += 10;
                DoBacklightControl(backlight_percentage);
            }

            DoBacklightPercent(backlight_percentage);
            StatusLabel7.Text = String.Format("BRIGHTNESS {0}", backlight_percentage);
            StatusLabel7.Update();
        }
```

Comment: You could just make those two buttons DISABLED, then only enable them when the "bright" button is pressed.  Use a Timer with a 10 second interval to disable them again from the Tick() event.  Each timer the up or down button is pressed, reset the Timer.  When the timer fires, it's because the bright, up, and/or down button was not pressed in the last ten seconds.

Comment: Idle_Mind’s comment sounds like the way to go using a timer, however, it is unclear what happens “after” the user clicks the up/down buttons? Is the user allowed to continue clicking the up/down buttons if they do this within the time limit? Should the time limit “re-set” after the up/down buttons are clicked? Should “both” up/down buttons be enabled when the “bright” button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new winform project, add three buttons named… `btnBright`, `btnUP` and `btnDown` to the form. The `Timer` is added in the code below.

When the form loads, set up the `Timer` `buttonTimer` properties, setting the interval to 10 seconds and wire up the `Tick` event to fire 10 seconds “after” the timer is started. Then “Disable” the up/down buttons.

When run, the up/down buttons will be disabled until the user clicks the “Bright” button, when clicked the up/down buttons are enable and the timer is started.  After the timer runs for 10 seconds its `Tick` event is fired where the code disables the up/down buttons and turns the timer off.

```
Timer buttonTimer;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  buttonTimer = new Timer();
  buttonTimer.Interval = 10000;
  buttonTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(buttonTimer_Tick);
  btnUP.Enabled = false;
  btnDown.Enabled = false;
}

private void buttonTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  btnUP.Enabled = false;
  btnDown.Enabled = false;
  buttonTimer.Stop();
}

private void btnBright_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  btnUP.Enabled = true;
  btnDown.Enabled = true;
  buttonTimer.Start();
}

private void btnUP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // unclear what to do here... we will let the timer continue
  // which will disable the button after 10 seconds regardless how many times up is clicked
}

private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // unclear what to do here... we will let the timer continue
  // which will disable the button after 10 seconds regardless how many times down is clicked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to declare a datetime field to store the time the user pressed [BRIGHT] button, then in the event of button UP check how much time has passed.

Something like this :

```
{ //Begin of form class code

    private DateTime _BrightPressed; //Field to store the time Bright button is presed

    //Method for Bright button. Add as event handler
    private void Brightbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this._BrightPressed = DateTime.Now; //Stores the time button has pressed
         // ... Code
    }
    
    //Method handler for Up Button
    private void Upbutton23_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         var JustNow = DateTime.Now; //Gets the time Up button is clicked
         //Calculates the time elapsed since bright button is pressed
         System.TimeSpan diffResult = JustNow.Subtract(this._BrightPressed); 

         if(diffResult.Seconds<=10) {
              // ... Code 
         }

    }        

} //End form class code
```